# webbrowser control shows a save as dialog instead of displaying a local .mhtml page

Tags: webbrowser-control, outlook-addin

This one has me scratching my head.

We have a "Previewer" which hosts a WebBrowser control.

When this "Previewer" is used to "preview" a Word document or Excel Spreadsheet I use some code to convert the document to a .mhtml file. I then tell the WebBrowser to navigate to that.

This works fine on many machines but not all. On some machines, instead of "navigating" to the mhtml and displaying it in the WebBrowser control, the WebBrowser control takes it upon itself to present a "Save As" dialog, asking the user to save the .mhtml file to their PC.

What is going on here, and how do I stop it?

Thanks

An example of the sort of file I try to navigate to:

```
"file://127.0.0.1/C$/Users/blahblahblahhere/AppData/Local/furthersubfoldershere/637183327673490444_Document1_486951.mhtml"
```

All I'm doing is

```
oWB.Navigate(....)
```

Ok.... this may also be relevant. This happens when a user is using an add-in we wrote in Outlook 365.... So the WebBrowser control is hosted in our Add-in in one of the forms it pops up as the user is doing their thing in Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I still don't know why it does this for an .mhtml file, but I found that converting it to .html instead actually works. I was reluctant to do that as a Word Document or an Excel Spreadsheet converted to HTML might produce an .HTML file with lots of associated files, e.g. for images. But while it does indeed do that, as it turns out it still works quite happily in the WebBrowser control. And without popping up that "save" dialog.

If you *must* use MHTML I have no solution for you, but if HTML is "good enough" for you, well, that's how I fixed it for myself.